# I'd like to select multiple items in my listView, and send them to another listView in another activity with the click of a button

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'd like to select multiple items in my listView, and send them to another listView in another activity with the click of a button. I'll provide some code, but I'm pretty clueless right now and can't find answers anywhere. When I run my application, everything looks fine as far as UI goes.

.xml file with the listview inside:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/beerProduct"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.28" >
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addtolist"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="75dp"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:text="@string/addtolist"
    android:textSize="26sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

.java calling the listview:
    package com.practice.practiceapp1;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

// Array of options --> Array Adapter --> ListView

public class Beer<object> extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_beer);

    populateListView();
}

private void populateListView() {
    // create list of items
    String[] beerItems = { "Miller Chill", "Miller Fortune",
            "Miller Genuine Draft", "Miller High Life",
            "Miller High Life Light", "Miller Lite", "Miller 64",
            "Milwaukee\'s Best Ice", "Milwaukee\'s Best Light",
            "Milwaukee\'s Best Premium" };

    // build adapter
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.beer_items, beerItems);

    // configure the ListView
    final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.beerProduct);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.beer, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

.xml containing listview properties:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minHeight="75dp"
android:textSize="26sp" >


</TextView>
```

Thanks!
Reagan

Comment: This is pretty broad. Which part are you stuck on? You should start by overriding `OnItemSelected`. And look at [CHOICE_MODE_MUKTIPLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:choiceMode)

Comment: search for "CAB android" (and yes, it can be used with support.v7)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to implement the

> [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)

interface. This interface allows you to send hole objects between activities.
I imagine that the object that you want to send is the ArrayAdapter.
You can find many tutorials on the internet to understand the mechanism better. 
In a few words you have to :

1. Implement the Parcelable interface in the class describes the objects that you want to send
2. In the sender class create a Bundle , put the parcelable into it and  send the hole bundle as Extra info before the transition

   ```
       Bundle newBundle = new Bundle();  
       mBundle.putParcelable(A_KEY, YourObjectThatYouWantToSend); // the key is the identifier for the parcelable
       newIntent.putExtras(newBundle);  
       startActivity(newIntent);
   ```
3. Receive the object in the receiver's activity

   ```
       (YourObjectThatYouWantToSend)getIntent().getParcelableExtra(A_KEY);
   ```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I'm going to try out the CAB as well to see what works best, but for now, the Parcelable is working.

Answer (score -1):

You should create a custom list. Because you have to hold  the values selected in the list. And you can do this in a getView() method of a custom list adapter. Below is a custom list adapter the way you can use. Create a `CustomArrayAdapter.java` class.

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
private final List<String> beerItems;
private final List<String> selectedBeerItems = new ArrayList<String>();

public CustomArrayAdapter (Activity context, List<String> beerItems) {

    super(context, R.layout.list_single_item, beerItems);
    this.context = context;
    this.beerItems= beerItems;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {



    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single_item, null, true);

    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_single_item_text);
    textView.setText(beerItems[position].toString());


    textView .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectedBeerItems.add(beerItems[position]);

        }
    });


    return rowView;
}

public List<String> getSelectedBeerItems() {
    return selectedBeerItems;
}


}
```

Here basically it creates a `selectedBeerItems()` list and only adds the selected beerItems to that list. Now, on the actvity, you should create an adapter and set it to the list;

```
    CustomArrayAdapter adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You can now retrieve the selected items in your activity, by calling the method inside the adapter. First you should create an empty list on your activity, then pupolate it with the selected items in the adapter as follows. Do it on your activity.

```
    List<String> selectedBeerItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    selectedBeerItems = adapter.getSelectedBeerItems();
```

Now that you have the selected beer items on your actvity side. You can just send this to another activity.